# Span of Transcendental Numbers

Tags: transcendental-numbers, transcendental-equations, transcendence-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two transcendental numbers.
Does there exist $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r$ cannot be expressed as any finite (integral) powers of $a$ and $b$ with rational coefficients?

For any finite $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, does the following hold?

$\sum_{i=0}^n c_ia^i + d_ib^i = r$

where $c_i, d_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

Edit: *Since there are answers that $r$ exists, please provide an example given any two transcendental numbers $a$ and $b$.*

That is find  $r\notin\{\,\sum_{i=0}^n(c_ia^i+d_ib^i)\;|\; c_i,d_i\in \Bbb Q\land 0\le n\in \Bbb Z\}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Otherwise, the [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ over be smaller than or equal to $2$. But it is actuallly infinite (in fact, it has the cardinality of the continuum).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If such a number $r$ exists, what may be an example? Any other transcendental number?

Comment: I cannot provide an example, since $r$ depends upon $a$ and $b$. And, no, it doesn't have to be transcendental.

Comment: If I choose $r = e^{a+b}$, will it work?

Comment: Not in general. Suppose that $b=-a$, for instance.

Comment: If $a+b \neq 0$, then would it work?

Comment: Again, not in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102794/discussion-between-drdebmath-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 1):

$\{\,\sum_{i=0}^n(c_ia^i+d_ib^i)\;|\; c_i,d_i\in \Bbb Q\land 0\le n\in \Bbb Z\}$ is countably infinite but $\Bbb R$ is uncountably infinite.

Comment: I am looking for a number which doesn't belong to the set. Possibly a method to generate such a number for any given a and b.